# Как перевести строку в число

Tags: c++, строки, парсер, double, nan

Имеется ли в с++ готовая функция которая бы могла попытаться преобразовать строку в число (`double` к примеру), и при неудаче возвращала бы не ноль, а к примеру `NAN`?

Comment: Да такое без проблем написать самому...

Comment: @harry, ну тут скорее вопрос лени. просто есть atof, и она почему-то при ошибочном вводе возвращает 0. Уже ли нет аналогов?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392665/converting-string-to-float-without-atof-in-c

Comment: Конечно, есть. См. [man strtod](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)

Comment: @Михаил Дёмин: `atof`? Функция `atof` не имеет практических применений. Базовой функцией перевода строки в `double` является функция `strtod`, которая сообщает об ошибках через `errno` и указатель. Вы пробовали пользоваться `strtod`? А то складывается впечатление, что вы пытаетесь решить несуществующую проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double my_atof(const char *str) {
    double d;
    try {
        d = std::stod(str);
    }
    catch (...) {
        return std::nan("");
    }
    return d;
}

int main() {

    double d = my_atof("0");
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    d = my_atof("0.0f");
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    d = my_atof("3.445");
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    d = my_atof("www");
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    d = my_atof("    ");
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

0
0
3.445
nan
nan

Comment: В вашем варианте некорректно обработается строка "0" и всё, что так или иначе обозначает 0, собственно основная причина вопроса в том, что нужно корректно обработать и ноль тоже, но при этом не заморачиваться с отдельной проверкой строки на то, является она 0 или нет

Comment: Изменил ответ. .....

Answer (score -3):

```
public:
static double ToDouble(
    String^ value
)
```

Пример:

```
double targetNumber = Convert::ToDouble(value2);
```

"При неудаче" - `try{} catch(...){}` в помощь

Comment: не .. это не с++

Comment: [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx) вы уверены?

Comment: Не против вашего ответа, но это не с++. По ссылке -- .NET Framework

Comment: Объясните подробнее в чем состоит ваше решение, а так же чем поможет `try{} catch(...){}`